# How to get answer ID in a question

Tags: support

How can I get the Answer ID in a question so I can reference someone to that particular answer?

Like if someone is asking a question on StackOverflow and I know a question which got the answer and I want to refer to that answer by means of URL Address.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the "share" link under the post.

Comment: Side note: removing the last set of numbers (your user id) is also acceptable.

Comment: Share under the `particular answer`, to be a bit more precise ;)

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add an image to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272708/6607497, but I got "*Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites*".
So I'm making a copy:

Use the "share" link under the answer:

[image]